# git log interleaved with submodules changes

Tags: git

I have two different commit hashes A and B from the main project. How do I obtain the list of changes from the submodules as well as the main project between the two main project commit hashes? For example, I have commit hashes A and B, how do I get all of the changes to the main project between A and B and all of the changes to the submodules between A and B?